# rcorr gives error where cor works perfectly (need p-values for correlation matrix)

Tags: r, correlation

I need to get p-values for my correlation matrix that I created using `cor`. Strangely when I use `rcorr`on the same data I get the following error:

```
Error in storage.mode(x) <- "double" : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Any suggestions?

below is my code for creating the correlation matrix(that gives error):

```
library(Hmisc)

corr < rcffull[,c("liwc_WC","liwc_informal","liwc_male",
                   "liwc_female","liwccsr_csrdic","liwc_negemo",
                   "liwc_posemo","liwc_risk")]
rcorr(corr)
```

this one is the one that works, but I don't get p-values:

```
cor(corr, use="complete.obs")
```

Comment: Is this `Hmisc::rcorr`? Please include the `library()` call when you're asking about something that's not in base R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Hmisc::rcorr` expects the input to be a `matrix` and will not automatically convert dataframes, even when they are all numeric. So you should just be able to call `as.matrix()` on your input, e.g.

```
x <- c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2)
y <- c(4,   1, 0, 1, 4)
z <- c(1,   2, 3, 4, NA)
v <- c(1,   2, 3, 4, 5)

df = data.frame(x, y, z, v)

# Fails with the same error as in the question
Hmisc::rcorr(df)
# Succeeds
Hmisc::rcorr(as.matrix(df))
```